# Why Files.exist() method not working in MockitoJUnitRunner

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Use Case: I want to load some dummy data from a json file using parent method in mockito.
When **initialize** method of parent class is invoked, **Files.exists** returns false whereas when I debug **initialize** method using main method it works.

```
 //child class
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UPIPreNotifyServiceTest extends BaseTest {
    @Mock
    private ISubscriptionContractv2Dao iSubscriptionContractv2Dao;

    @Test
    public void testPreNotifyService() {
        BaseTest baseTest = new BaseTest();
        JsonElement jsonElement = baseTest.initialize();
        JsonElement element = this.jsonObject.get("contract_with_active_status");
        SubscriptionContractv2 subscriptionContractv2 = new Gson().fromJson(element,SubscriptionContractv2.class);
        String subsPaymode = subscriptionContractv2.getSubsPaymentMode();

    }
}



//Parent class
@Slf4j
public class BaseTest {
    public JsonObject jsonObject;
    private static String FILE_NAME = "/subscription/src/test/jsonObject.json";

    public JsonObject initialize() {
        try {
            String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            String fullPath = workingDir + FILE_NAME;
            if(Files.exists(Paths.get(fullPath))) { // It always gives me false but when i call this piece of code using main method this works
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(fullPath));
                this.jsonObject = parser.parse(reader).getAsJsonObject();
                return jsonObject;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("File not found with name: {}",FILE_NAME);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error("Exception occurred while loading json file",e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `fullPath` resolve to the same value each time? Try debugging it.

Comment: Why do you spy on `BaseTest`? You are not verifying anything on it.

Comment: @knittl Even we remove spy on BaseTest, it won't work

Comment: @user591 wait, I'm confused now. You are extending `BaseTest`. Why are you instantiating an instance of the base class in the child class? Either you extend or you compose. You can't do both (well, obviously you can; but you shouldn't)